# How to change scope when controller is changed using Angular routes without using $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/U9tL95qS5AgsPu6nNwVD/

I am able to change ng-view with templateUrl. But it is not updating {{msg}} when I am updating it using  $scope.msg in every new controller.

Is there a way to update it without using $rootscope. Since I have heard that $rootScope practise is bad.

I guess I Am not registering the controller ?? 
I am new to Angular.

I dont know how to use services

in index.html

```
app.controller("redCtrl", ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {
  $scope.msg = "I love red";   //NOT WORKING  **************
}]);
```

Comment: Does that solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes . Thanks eveyone

Comment: Mark the answer then.

Comment: How to mark as answer ??? Could you post the link to do so

Comment: there will we right sign in the answer left side .Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this plnkr  https://plnkr.co/edit/rvIZouNydPpwFgsIiVaf

@Rohitas Behera The reason is simple you are using

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>

    <a href="#!red">Red</a>
    <a href="#!green">Green</a>
    <a href="#!blue">Blue</a>


    <div ng-view>

    </div>
          {{msg}}   <!-- why using here !>

  </div>
```

so this time the msg is in scope of `maincontroller` . There are not other controller in scope

To do so remove {{msg}} from index.html and place it in there respective page.

Like this.
blue.html

```
<div style="background-color:#2196f3;">
<h1>Blue  {{msg}}</h1>
</div>
```

same for all html page.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add {{msg}} in every template.like this

```
 <div style="background-color:#f44336;">
  <h1>Red</h1>
 {{msg}}
 </div>
```

and remove {{msg}} form index.html page because maincontroller is working for index page and the modified page like this

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>

<a href="#!red">Red</a>
<a href="#!green">Green</a>
<a href="#!blue">Blue</a>


<div ng-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To alter the value `{{msg}}` in different context/controller, you will need to write `{{msg}}` in individual .html files where you have set the scope of respective controller.

As of now the variable is accessible only to your `mainController` as it is seen in `index.html` only, hence the value never changes.
You need to remove it from `index.html` and put it in every html.

> here is the fixed [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ymk7SdotZbxgKshy1es1?p=preview)